# android-maven-plugin debug keeps waiting for debugger forever

Tags: java, android, maven, debugging

I'm using android-maven-plugin, when I try to debug the code, with the hope it stops on break point, it keeps waiting for debugger....
I've got working once doing nothing special.

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>es.mycode.sgcv</groupId>
<artifactId>sgcv-android</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>sgcv-android</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <platform.version> 4.1.1.4</platform.version>
    <android.plugin.version>4.0.0-rc.2</android.plugin.version>
    <android.home>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</android.home>
    <android.sdk.path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</android.sdk.path>
    <android.version>4.2.2_r3</android.version>
<android.platform>17</android.platform>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>android-support</id>
        <url>file://${env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
 <groupId>android</groupId>
 <artifactId>android</artifactId>
 <version>${android.version}</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.mindpipe.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-logging-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencias para trazas -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.loopj.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-async-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
        <version>4.46</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osmdroid</groupId>
        <artifactId>osmdroid-android</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osmdroid.bonuspack</groupId>
        <artifactId>osmbonuspack</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.grundid.opendatalab</groupId>
        <artifactId>geojson-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-android</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>23.0.1</version>
        <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
        <version>23.0.1</version>
        <type>aar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version> <!-- use latest release -->
    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                <fork>false</fork>
                <release>false</release>
                <includeLibsJarsFromAar>true</includeLibsJarsFromAar>
                <resourceDirectory>${basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <assetsDirectory>${basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <androidManifestFile>${basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${basedir}/libs</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                <run>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                </run>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>23</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
  </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[4.3.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>emma</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I run the app using this goal:

-Dandroid.run.debug=true android:run

Anyone has any suggestion?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't figured out how this should work with Android debug option as well, but I was able to launch the debugger manually (I presume your device has debug option available):

- Deploy your application on your device as you do with Maven usually with **no debug options** and launch it (`clean install android:deploy android:run`).
- Now switch to DDMS view (I'm still using Eclipse and not Android studio, so maybe it's not the same in Android Studio)
- Under your device identifier in DDMS view you see the package name of your app. Beside that there are numbers. The second number is the port you have to connect to.
- Create a debug configuration `Remote Java Application`. Project name is the root project, host is `localhost` and the port is the given port of DDMS, it's `8600` in my case. Connection type is `Socket Attach`.
- Now click debug and set anywhere a breakpoint in code. The debugger will stop there.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I had to launch the debugger manually, but didn't know how to do it.